# How does server returns data without client requesting in long polling?

Tags: jquery, ajax, real-time, comet, long-polling

I implemented the very easy and lazy method of requesting data from server via ajax in interval for real time affect.

But I want to opt for long polling/ comet technique as they encourage server to push data when there's one instead of client pulling constantly even when there's none.

I completely understand the way long polling and comet work. But I wish to see the coding part where server pushes when there's data to client.

How can for a request made by client long ago (long polling) can server push when there's data? I don't understand this part. Can someone show in coding please?

currently i check via ajax for new data in interval. Now, how can this be modified to implement long polling where server returns automatically when there's data without client asking for it?

```
(function notify(){
    $.each(id, function(k, v){
      jQuery.ajax({

           method: "POST",
           url: "/notification.php",
           "data": v,
           error: function() {
             reject('error');
           },  
           success: function(result) {
             console.log(result.data);         
           }
       });
    })
setTimeout(function(){
    notify();
 }, 1000);
})()
```

Since this question marked as duplicate:

I said I fully understand the concept of long polling and comet. I'm here not to understand the concept but for the code that actually implement that concept!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

Comment: Basically the server just doesn't respond until data becomes available. BTW, Regular old PHP really isn't designed for this, as it is not really scale-able and you will quickly use up all resources.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, i'll make sure my server uses php5 and above. But how does the server respond, can you show the pseudo code?

Comment: It responds the same as normal, just after waiting for something to happen. Also it doesn't matter if your using PHP 5 or 7, in a typical setup every active requests needs a PHP process to run. Long polling means that every request has a PHP process almost constantly idling, which will quickly eat up resources.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, the conclusion is?

Comment: Don't use traditional PHP for such things.

Comment: Don't use php5 and above for such things. You need either a non-blocking framework (reactphp, amphp etc.) or something with very lightweight threads like java, C# or C++. One of the reasons node.js is so popular is because it is by default non-blocking so can be used for long polling projects without any additional change in how you write code.

Comment: @slebetman, I'mm quite interested in nodejs too..but one problm I consider is, nodeJs has to be installed. I'm afraid my non-tech client would find it difficult to install it on their server...some are even using shared hosting..Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer here:

http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

I opted for the second example given in the site : comet with classic ajax
It works like charm. Below is the code for index.html (client page) in jquery also taken from the site..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Comet demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--     <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
<div id="content"></div>
<div style="margin: 5px 0;">
<form id="cometForm" action="javascript:void(0);" method="get">
<input id="word" type="text" name="word" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
function handleResponse(response){
$('#content').append('<div>' + response['msg'] + '</div>');
}

var timestamp = 0;
var url = './chat_backend.php';
var noerror = true;
var ajax;

function connect() {
ajax = $.ajax(url, {
type: 'get',
data: { 'timestamp' : timestamp },
success: function(transport) {
eval('var response = '+transport);
timestamp = response['timestamp'];
handleResponse(response);
noerror = true;
},
complete: function(transport) {
(!noerror) && setTimeout(function(){ connect() }, 5000) || connect();
noerror = false;
}
});
}

function doRequest(request) {
$.ajax(url, {
type: 'get',
data: { 'msg' : request }
});
}

$('#cometForm').on('submit', function(){
doRequest($('#word').val());
$('#word').val('');
return false;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
connect();
});
})(jQuery);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```